# iPad (3G models only) Safari crash

Tags: ipad, safari, crash

I'm using deck.js (http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/) to recreate a company powerpoint presentation, using a fair bit of CSS3 animations and Javascript.

Testing through development on my wifi-only iPad2 it's been fine, but checking on a wifi+3G iPad1, 2, & 3 the page crashes Safari on page load (iPhone 4S works fine).

Some basic debugging (deleting slides one by one) suggests that it's the size of the DOM that is forcing the crash, as it works fine when I reduce the presentation down from 31 slides to 21.

The total size of the page is about 4.3MB, and I've tried using an appcache manifest to no avail.

I've read on various forums that many people are having issues with iOS 5.1 Safari crashing - does anyone have any experience of the iPad 3G models crashing under the strain of a complex DOM?

Any thoughts and suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is, it seems to be a limitation of deck.js on such devices. Martin Fowler reported the same problems and ended up loading slides incrementally as a workaround (http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Infodeck.html).

It would be helpful to see if the problem comes from loading the DOM or from displaying it (the default deck.js themes are not optimized for display efficiency). Unfortunately, I cannot test as I don't have an ipad, but what I would recommend to try and hide all slides and see if there is still a crash. Some CSS code to do that:

```
.deck-container > .slide:not(.deck-current), .deck-container > .slide:not(.deck-child-current) { display: none; }
```